# Determining how much of each payment type is actually used with multiple payments and amounts

Tags: php

I am working on a retail application. Often in retail sales can have multiple payment types and amounts (and multiple of the same type over a period of time). I have run across a bug and want to make sure the fix I have makes sense.

The total of these payments could be greater than or equal to the payment type (For a sale). I am running across an odd scenario that I am not sure I have the right idea in mind.

Example problem I am having:

Sale total `+20` they pay `-2` on `cash` and then `+22` on `debit`. The function below reports `+20` cash and `0` on debit. I would like a way for it to report `-2` on `cash` and `+22` on `debit`.

There are other simple scenarios such as a total sale of `+18` and they pay `+20` in `cash`. This scenario works and reports `+18` in `cash`.

Also payments can be entered in different orders; but I would think it should do it based on the order it is entered.

The problem I am running into is negative payments on positive sales.

The logic first gets the total sale balance. (Could be positive for a sale or negative for a return; or even 0). From here it checks the payment amount to be positive or negative.

1. If positive it tries to use as much as possible from the payment amount up to the total sale balance (I think this is right).

**2. The inverse logic exists for negative payment types. I think having a negative payment in a positive sale is causing issues. I am not sure how to fix this and I did NOT envision this scenario.**

After these checks it subtracts the payment from the total sale balance and does the same logic for all payments.

```
$total_sale_balance = $sales_totals[$sale_id];      
foreach($payment_rows as $payment_row)
{
    if ($payment_row['payment_amount'] >=0)
    {
        $payment_amount = $payment_row['payment_amount'] <= $total_sale_balance ? $payment_row['payment_amount'] : $total_sale_balance;
    }
    else
    {
        $payment_amount = $payment_row['payment_amount'] >= $total_sale_balance ? $payment_row['payment_amount'] : $total_sale_balance;
    }
    if (!isset($payment_data[$payment_row['payment_type']]))
    {
        $payment_data[$payment_row['payment_type']] = array('payment_type' => $payment_row['payment_type'], 'payment_amount' => 0 );
    }

    $exists = $this->_does_payment_exist_in_array($payment_row['payment_id'], $payments_by_sale[$sale_id]);

    if ($total_sale_balance != 0 && $exists)
    {
        $payment_data[$payment_row['payment_type']]['payment_amount'] += $payment_amount;
    }
    $total_sale_balance-=$payment_amount;                   
}
```

I am looking for a different way to look at the problem as I am running into issues with different types of payments for sales + returns.

Do I need to have 4 possible pieces of logic? (This seems to make sense)

1: Sale Total Positive, Payment type Positive

```
$payment_amount = $payment_row['payment_amount'] <= $total_sale_balance ? $payment_row['payment_amount'] : $total_sale_balance;
```

2: Sale Total Positive, Payment Type Negative

```
$payment_amount = $payment_row['payment_amount'];
```

3: Sale Total Negative, Payment Type Positive

```
$payment_amount = $payment_row['payment_amount'];
```

4: Sale Total Negative, Payment Type Negative

```
$payment_amount = $payment_row['payment_amount'] >= $total_sale_balance ? $payment_row['payment_amount'] : $total_sale_balance;
```

I just want to make sure I cover all scenarios.

Here is the final code with the above logic....Am I overlooking anything? Does this seems to make sense?

```
$total_sale_balance = $sales_totals[$sale_id];      
foreach($payment_rows as $payment_row)
{
    //Postive sale total, positive payment
    if ($sales_totals[$sale_id] >= 0 && $payment_row['payment_amount'] >=0)
    {
        $payment_amount = $payment_row['payment_amount'] <= $total_sale_balance ? $payment_row['payment_amount'] : $total_sale_balance;
    }//Negative sale total negative payment
    elseif ($sales_totals[$sale_id] < 0 && $payment_row['payment_amount']  < 0)
    {
        $payment_amount = $payment_row['payment_amount'] >= $total_sale_balance ? $payment_row['payment_amount'] : $total_sale_balance;
    }//Positive Sale total negative payment
    elseif($sales_totals[$sale_id] >= 0 && $payment_row['payment_amount']  < 0)
    {
        $payment_amount = $payment_row['payment_amount'];
    }//Negtive sale total postive payment
    elseif($sales_totals[$sale_id] < 0 && $payment_row['payment_amount']  >= 0)
    {
        $payment_amount = $payment_row['payment_amount'];
    }

    if (!isset($payment_data[$payment_row['payment_type']]))
    {
        $payment_data[$payment_row['payment_type']] = array('payment_type' => $payment_row['payment_type'], 'payment_amount' => 0 );
    }

    $exists = $this->_does_payment_exist_in_array($payment_row['payment_id'], $payments_by_sale[$sale_id]);

    if ($total_sale_balance != 0 && $exists)
    {
        $payment_data[$payment_row['payment_type']]['payment_amount'] += $payment_amount;
    }

    $total_sale_balance-=$payment_amount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that all negative transactions happen first(which, for all I know, you could be doing somewhere else). With your final code block, a total of +20, a cash transaction of -2, and a debit transaction of +22 everything totals correctly to 0. If, however, the debit transaction comes first then you end with a total balance of +2 because the first logic block(positive+positive) would cap the debit transaction at 20 because that is the total balance at that point.

Another thing you may or may not want is that if the total is negative and the payment is positive, then the charge will still occur in full, pushing the total further negative(i.e. total = -10 and payment = 10, the total will become -20). Since your first logic block directly attempts to counter negative balances, you may not want that.

An alternative approach could be:

```
$total_sale_balance = $sales_totals[$sale_id];
$positive_transactions = array(); // or [] if you're using a new enough PHP
$negative_transactions = array();
foreach ($payment_rows as $payment_row) {
  // Let's just check if the transaction exists here.
  // No need to do anything else with it if this check fails.
  if (!$this->_does_payment_exist_in_array($payment_row['payment_id'], $payments_by_sale[$sale_id])) { continue; }

  if ($payment_row['payment_amount'] > 0) {
    $positive_transactions[] = $payment_row;
  } else if ($payment_row['payment_amount'] < 0) {
    $negative_transactions[] = $payment_row;
  }
} // No logic for == 0 since it doesn't look like you're actually doing anything with that.

foreach ($negative_transactions as $transaction) {
  $total_sale_balance -= $transaction['payment_amount'];
  $payment_data[$transaction['payment_type']]['payment_amount'] += $transaction['payment_amount'];
}

foreach ($positive_transactions as $transaction) {
  if ($total_sale_balance <= 0) { break; }
  $amount_to_pay = ( $transaction['payment_amount'] < $total_sale_balance ? $transaction['payment_amount'] : $total_sale_balance );
  $total_sale_balance -= $amount_to_pay;
  $payment_data[$transaction['payment_type']]['payment_amount'] += $amount_to_pay;
}
```

If you can ignore the fact that I obviously don't adhere to some coding standards, you can see that I shifted a few things around to make it more durable and save some compute cycles.

Putting the 'payment exists' check first in the initial loop basically just skips over the transaction all together if that check fails, no need to put any more logic anywhere else to deal with that and no compute time is wasted trying to logic our way through transactions we're not going to do anything with anyway.

Next, by splitting the transactions into positive and negative, you can simplify the if-else logic and ensure that transactions happen in an order that prevents overcharging and maintains sanity.

In the negative block, there's no need to do any additional logic, because(as in your code above) negative transactions can't fail based on the total balance.

In the positive block, the only necessary checks are to constrain the payment amount to the total. By first checking if the total has been met, we can just end the loop as soon as the required amount has been met, or if the total is still positive, but lower than the transaction amount, we can just constrain it.

Also worth noting, if you delete the if statement at the top of the positive block, then if the total is negative then the payment would automatically be constrained to a negative amount which may or may not be desired, it depends on whether or not you would want to, for instance, credit back a negative total balance. I.E if the purchase involved a refund(so the total started out negative - since the logic wouldn't allow a negative total otherwise) of $20(total = -20) then the the next positive transaction would be constrained to -20 which would zero out the total and (somewhere else, either in code or the real world) give me my money. Of course, in that case you'd probably want to include 0 amount transactions in the positive list(change that if-statement in the first block to  `>= 0`) since that would likely be the transaction starting point for a refund.